# How to mount floating loft stairs to the wall

Tags: walls, attic, stairs

I'm looking for a nice way to make a stairs for loft bed in the apartment. I definitely want to use space under stairs for storage but I don't want to use *all* space.

I like an idea [shown here](http://tinyhouseswoon.com/sherwood-tiny-home/) (photos below and [video](https://youtu.be/FjC2YnNNpaE?t=40)).

I have larger room so I'd like to have wider stairs about 500-600mm (in case if that doesn't affect strength of a construction).

Does anyone know how to mount stairs that way? Thanks :)

[image: stairs view 1]

[image: stairs view 2]

Comment: Where did you find the images? I'm not sure I could bring myself to climb those stairs. o_O

Comment: @Isherwood: [A 160 square feet tiny house on wheels with storage stairs in Londonderry, Vermont](http://tinyhouselistings.com/listing/sherwood-tiny-house-on-a-trailer/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the boxes themselves appear to be structurally adequate to carry human weight. The 3-4 inch lap between the boxes also provides some stiffness and weight bearing. The trick would be in fastening them to the walls in such a way as to withstand the large tensile (pulling) forces. A few ideas come to mind:

1. Decorative or hidden angle brackets, mounted to the wall and the upper surface of each step.
2. Dual-thread bolts, with lag threads into the wall framing, and machine thread on the extension, which would need to pass through most of the upper step panel with washer and nut applied behind the face trim.
3. Direct framing attachment, where the stair components are fitted around the wall framing and anchored to it. In this case, insulation and wall paneling would be fit around the stair components.

However it's done, the individual boxes need to be well-built, using an appropriate adhesive, quality sheet goods, and mechanical fasteners where possible.

Answer (score 0):

The box itself is needed to pull this off, the box must shoulder against the wall to stop any flexing. Typically, you'd install picture frames of 2x4's on the wall, screwed (preferably Lag Screwed) into the studs & floor joists. I wouldn't go any wider than his 500mm (his look shorter than the 600mm kitchen counter). This isn't good for a structure not made for it & the boxes don't like it much either.

Then, you'd slip over your 3/4" plywood boxes (glued & screwed) & screw them to the picture frame all of the way around. And, screw the boxes to each other in 2 rows, like what he did at the very top panel. You'd actually build & connect the boxes first & dry fit them against the wall to then just pencil trace inside of the boxes for all of the needed picture frames that would go onto the wall first.

Then, you'd skin over your boxes & their unsightly screws with 1/4" plywood panels for concealment. Finally, as he did, you attach face frames to beautify all of the plywood edges.

More traditional box stairs are much better & more versatile storage solutions. Since, they can be any width, don't need additional framing & the supporting boxes can be drawers, cabinets or a full closet or armoire at the back end (if you put a TV or shelf on the side) or back side.